# How to find feature importance from one hot vector input in an SVM model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am training an SVM on a list of one hot encoded vectors that look like this (its actually shape (179, 42621), but for the purpose of example, lets say its as below):

```
vectors = 
[
[0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,1],
[0,0,0,1],
[0,0,0,1],
[0,0,0,1]
]
```

The labels look like this:

```
labels = 
[
[0],
[1],
[1],
[2],
[0]
]
```

I have trained an SVM using the code below:

```
X = vectors
y = labels

# fixing class imbalance
sm = SMOTE(random_state=42)
X, y = sm.fit_resample(X, y)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

svc = LinearSVC()
svc.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = svc.predict(X_test)
```

Is there anyway I can get an idea of how important each feature is in the feature input vector in terms of its predictive power?

In other words, how can I tell how important the 0th, 1st, 2nd, and 3rd feature in the feature vector is in terms of prediction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a linear model, you can work directly with the coefficients to get the feature importances. You could plot by constructing a dataframe (set the index to the attributes so the tick labels are set too):

```
pd.Series(abs(svc.coef_[0])).sort_values(ascending=False).head(10).plot.barh()
```

Comment: remember you need to set `penalty='l1'` (linear kernel) in order to use `coef_` attribute

Comment: I think `LinearSVC` has it by default @lalfab

Comment: the documentation says `penalty: str, ‘l1’ or ‘l2’ (default=’l2’)`

Comment: The kernel is linear in any case, as its name suggests. And it looks like the coefficients are accessible from both penalty settings @lalfab

Comment: It is true, my error was thinking in obtain a sparse solution.